# How to make clang ignore c-c++ incompatibility errors?

Tags: c, c++11, compilation, clang, compatibility

I have a program that is written in C. The original makefile had "gnu99". Clang compiles it without extra commandline options. But if I include a header-only library written in c++11 (variadic templates => cannot compile separately), then hell breaks loose ...

compiling simply with 'clang inputfile.c staticlib.a -lsomelib' gives errors like:

```
error: unknown type name 'namespace'
error: unknown type name 'template'
... much much more ...
```

so it tries to compile c++ as plain c

if I try 'clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ inputfile.c staticlib.a -lsomelib', then:

```
error: expected ';' after enum
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'rssFeedState *' with an lvalue of type 'void *'
... much much more ... !!!!! I want to make it ignore these !!!!
```

rewriting the .c file to compile as c++ is the very last option

How do I make clang handle the situation properly?

ie: compile the .c file as c, but handle one of the included headers as c++11 (instantiate the variadic templates, recognize namespaces, c++11 standard library, ...)

Comment: You can't just "handle one of the includes" specially - a header (through `#include`) is copied literally into the including file. You need to compile that file as `-std=c++11`.

Comment: apperently at least 1+4 people do not know the solution

Comment: I should reformulate the question then: how to make it swallow those plain-old-c statements? eg: typedef enum {bla foo} xyz;

Comment: "How do I make clang handle the situation properly?" -- It's not Clang's job to handle this. Either you write C, or you write C++. Also note that Clang is probably the strictest compiler there is.

Answer (score 7):

Is completely and utterly impossible. The only way to include a C++ header is to be writing C++ code. So the *only* option is to rewrite your C source to be valid C++. This is not a big stretch for most C.

Comment: isn't there a permissive or compatibility mode, so void* assigning and classic typedef's are not errors?

Comment: I mean, why can it let "error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'rssFeedState *' with an lvalue of type 'void *'" pass as a c-compiler but not as c++

Comment: @user1358: Because the standards say so? C++ had a good reason to remove implicit conversion from `void*` - cast it.

Comment: I was hoping that there is some -permissive flag that lets me ignore that, btw: not a single compiler is fully stadards compliant by default

Comment: @user1358: There's a VAST difference between -permissive and *completely changing the language*.